# Localization - linking to other pages goes to 404

Tags: localization

I have a localized site set up where the language switcher and translations are working fine. However when I link to internal pages it goes to a 404.

general.php has this:

```
 //local only
 'etf-craft.dev' => array(
    'devMode' => true,
    'siteUrl' => array(
       'en' => 'http://etf-craft.dev/en/',
       'fr' => 'http://etf-craft.dev/fr/'
   ),
   'environmentVariables' => array(
        'environment' => 'local',
        'basePath' => 'D:\sites\etf-craft\public_html',
        'baseUrl'  => 'http://etf-craft.dev',
    )
),
```

site structure is like this:

- craft
- public
- public/en/
- public/fr/

index.php in /fr/ and /en/ directories contains the following where french says /fr/ instead of /en/:

```
// Path to your craft/ folder
$craftPath = '../../craft';

// Tell Craft to serve the English content
define('CRAFT_LOCALE', 'en');
```

One link I've created that 404s on me is:

```
  <li>
    <a href="/{{ craft.locale }}/news" class="news">{{ "News" | t}}
      <i class="arrow right"></i>
    </a>
  </li>
```

What I expect is that it takes me to http://etf-craft.dev/en/news and the news page shows up. However I end up going to a 404.

However if I manually remove the /en/ from the address bar the news template shows up correctly.

- **not working** - http://etf-craft.dev/en/news
- **working** - http://etf-craft.dev/news

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Does each folder (en|fr) have an .htaccess file too?

Comment: It did not, but I copied one in now and no change.

Comment: Did you update the craftPath var in both index.php `$craftPath = '../../craft';`?

Comment: @Natetronn Yes that was previously set correctly - updating the post now with that information

Comment: Not sure if it matters either way but, looks like you're missing a comma in the siteUrl array `'fr' => 'http://etf-craft.dev/fr/',`

Comment: @Natetronn And now it's working. Thank you.

Comment: @CreateSean can you add an official answer and accept that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off, make sure you have .htaccess files in both the en and fr folders and this per the [localization guide](https://craftcms.com/docs/localization-guide#step-5-set-up-the-files).

Secondly, you're missing a comma in the siteUrl array:

```
'siteUrl' => array(
    'en' => 'http://etf-craft.dev/en/',
    'fr' => 'http://etf-craft.dev/fr/' <--------add comma here-----
),
```

Comment: That comma isn't necessary there...

Comment: Aside from avoiding future syntax errors, should he add other languages in the future, you're right. Then again,  ¯\_(ツ)_/¯